# ERROR: syntax error at or near "psql" when importing database

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, psql

I am trying to import a .sql file into my new created database. I used

```
docker exec -it <idOfContainer> psql -U <user> <database_name>
```

to specify the database I want to use. Then I tried to import the .sql file to the database using the command

```
psql <databasename> -f "<path/to/file.sql>";
```

but this error appears

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql <databasename> -f "<path/to/file.sql>";
        ^
```

I am new in using postgres and databases, so no idea what to do, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're on the Postgres command line, i.e. "inside the database". In there you write SQL. You'll wanna execute that command on the command line, i.e. where you currently write `psql -U ...`.

Answer (score -1):

Your docker exec is wrong, you only need the `'-i'`

The -it executes tty which will get you to run into your container.
Importing databases can be done outside the container.

```
cat database.sql | docker exec -i <dockercontainername> psql -U <user> <databasename>
```

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference for this setup whether `psql` runs on a tty or not.